# Alfresco SDK Custom REST API without WebScripts

Tags: spring, rest, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

It's possible to expose custom REST services in Alfresco SDK AMP without **Alfresco WebScripts** but using other methods like **Jersey (JAX-RS)** or **Spring REST Controllers** since it has Spring framework support ?

Answer (score 0):

Never done it, but I think that you can.

Given that Alfresco is a Spring application, you can create your beans using a framework integrated with Spring and inject the Alfresco services as dependencies.

With these dependencies, you can access the Alfresco repository.

I do not know how easy it would be to reuse the authentication that is free for webscripts.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a library provided by [Daniel Gradecak](https://github.com/dgradecak)
. It provides simple samples which are very helpful. As far I understood, the library provide a Spring MVC wrapper around the WebScripts. You can check out [here](https://github.com/dgradecak/alfresco-mvc).